# Insert functions via for loop to async

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, node-async

I have the following function:

```
module.exports = {
  listAccounts: function (callback) {
    var acc = [];
    var calls = [];

    function processAccounts(account, cb) {
      client.getAddressesByAccount(account, function (err, addresses) {
        console.log('getting account', account);
        acc.push({name: account, addresses: addresses});
        return cb();
      });
    }

    client.listAccounts(function (err, res) {
      if (err)
        return callback(err)
      else {
        for (var key in res) {
          calls.push(
            function (cb) {
              processAccounts(key, cb);
            }
          );
        }


        async.parallel(calls, function (err, results) {
          console.log(acc);
        })

      }
    })

  }

}
```

What I want to do is to use the for loop in order to push all the functions to the `calls` array and then run `async.parallel` to run all the functions.

The problem is, that the calls array looks like this after the for loop finishes:

```
function (cb) {
              processAccounts(key, cb);
            },function (cb) {
              processAccounts(key, cb);
            },function (cb) {
              processAccounts(key, cb);
            }
```

It does not translate the `key` to the actual value but keeps it as `key`

Comment: Try `res[key]` to get the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use function to create a new scope where the value can be container in the closure.

```
var res = {a:'hello', b:'howdy'};
var calls = [];

for (var key in res) {
    calls.push(
        (function(k) {
            return function (cb) {
                console.log('say: ' + res[k] + ' to ' + cb);
            }
        })(key)
    );
}

calls[0]('you');
calls[1]('me');
```

prints:

say: hello to you

say: howdy to me

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want here is async.each

```
async.each(calls, function(key, cb) {
  processAccounts(key, cb);
},
function(err){
    if (err)
       console.log('oh no!', err);

    console.log('all accounts processed');
});
```